# Binding Google Chrome's bookmarks

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, search, address-bar

I used to type

> y QUERY

in the Firefox address bar and get `http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%s&aq=f` (`http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=QUERY&aq=f` in this particular case).

How can I do that in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/) so Chrome will automatically pick up its OpenSearch provider information, then right-click on the address bar and choose *Edit search engines...*

**On Chrome 10 (the current beta version) and later:**  click in the middle box immediately to the right of *YouTube Video Search*, replace the `youtube.com` with `y`, and close the preferences tab.

**On Chrome 9 (the current stable version) and earlier:**  click on *YouTube Video Search*, choose *Edit*, replace the `youtube.com` in the *Keyword* box with *y*, and click *Close*.

Now you can search YouTube by just typing `y query` into the Omnibox (address bar).  Notice that after you type `y` and a space, the left side of the address bar changes to indicate that you are about to search YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

- Click on the "wrench" and open
  Options
- On the Basics tab, click the
  **Manage** button in the Search section
- Click **Add**
- Fill the Name (**Youtube**), Keyword (**y**) and URL (`http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%s&aq=f`)

You should be able to use it now by typing

> y SOMETHING

to Chrome's URL bar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't sync custom searches ([yet](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=15548)) and XMarks doesn't convert them between browsers, so I created a service called [Shortmarks](http://shortmarks.com) that lets you use custom searches from any browser by setting Shortmarks as the default search engine.  I've been using it for almost a year now and am of course biased, but I love it.